# Adobe Air on iPhone - No audio if phone rings

Tags: ios, iphone, actionscript-3, air

My app has a section for playing audio:

```
chnl = new SoundChannel();          
mp3 = new Sound();
mp3.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, onErr);
mp3.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onComplete);
mp3.load(new URLRequest(fil.url));
```

While the sound is playing if the phone rings (or an alarm is activated), then the application stops playing, that is normal. But when I try to re-play the audio, it does not work anymore unless I close and re-open the app.

This does not happen if I minimize the app and re-launch it, or the phone rings on Android. It just happens on iPhone.

As a workaround, when I add this line:

```
SoundMixer.audioPlaybackMode  =  AudioPlaybackMode.VOICE;
```

The problem will solve! However, the audio will then only play through the earpiece, and not the Speaker. Even if I set:

```
SoundMixer.useSpeakerphoneForVoice = true;
```

Any ideas, please??

Comment: No iPhone here but is there a way to detect these audio interruptions (calls & alarms)? Why not just note the audio position at the cut-off time and then afterwards you make a new channel (but using same Sound object) and play audio from last known position? You could do all this new Channel stuff in a `prepareAudioChann()` function and just run it whenever needed.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, unfortunately, I can't find a way to detect these audio interruptions (calls & alarms). No event listeners.

Comment: **(1)** See if maybe [**this idea**](https://community.adobe.com/t5/air/air-33-ios-audio-stops-working-after-quot-interruption-quot/m-p/10811743?page=1#M55936) works okay on _your version_ of the AIR SDK **(2)** Try the newest AIR SDK (version 33.1.1 if I'm not mistaken). **(3)** See if there is a free ANE extension out there that detects audio mute and notifies your app code to react accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for the link, seems like I have to use an ANE as you said! Since Event.DEACTIVATE does not fire when the iPhone rings (unlike in Android) and there is no Event Listener for that in as3. Thank you!